# UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView

Tags: uiwebview, applet, app-store, app-store-connect, mobile-application

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Kill Corona stress-relief game" 1.0 (1.0). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

I have searched in the code for the UIWebView but there is no single instance of this still apple rejecting app.

Comment: May be one of your libraries is using uiwebview.

Comment: Hit grep -r "UIWebView" .  and check what libraries using "UIWebView". and update the library.

Comment: Actually this code was exported from Unity and this web view was hidden somewhere in Unity code. I just changed Unity version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this section "UIWebView Deprecation and App Store Rejection (ITMS-90809)" here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos

"Starting in April 2020, Apple will reject apps that still use the deprecated UIWebView API"
So you should have:

- "Xamarin.Forms 4.5 or higher"
- "Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher"
- "Remove references to UIWebView"

Also check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview#uiwebview-deprecation

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion if you are generating build from unity.

Please update of plugins if possible. and use below versions of unity. and also check URL.

Use this unity version: 2017.4, 2018.4, 2019.1, 2019.2, 2019.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkCBj.png)

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-unitywebrequest-errors-large-packets-with-examples

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-apple-throws-deprecated-api-usage-warning-for-using-uiwebview-when-submitting-builds-to-the-app-store-connect

https://forum.unity.com/threads/itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-new-apps-that-use-uiwebview-are-no-longer-accepted.883510/